# How to get Selected value of dynamically created checkboxlist in for loop

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, c#-4.0, selecteditem, checkboxlist

I have Array of checkboxlist, which is dynamically created, now i want to get selected values of checkboxlist in for loop , my code is below

protected void OnbtnNext1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        for (int i = 0; i < this.cbCountry.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (cbCountry.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                itemsCountry.Add(cbCountry.Items[i].Value);
                countCountry++;
            }
        }

        PopulateWaveCheckBoxes(itemsCountry);
        this.pnlWave.Visible = true;
    }


    private void PopulateWaveCheckBoxes(ArrayList items)
    {
        Label[] lbls = new Label[items.Count];
        CheckBoxList cblWave = new CheckBoxList[items.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            lbls[i] = new Label();
            lbls[i].Text = items[i].ToString();
            cblWave[i] = new CheckBoxList();
            cblWave[i].ID = "Checkbox" + i.ToString();
            cblWave[i].Items.Add(new ListItem("Wave 1"));
            cblWave[i].Items.Add(new ListItem("Wave 2"));
            cblWave[i].Items.Add(new ListItem("Wave 3"));
            cblWave[i].Items.Add(new ListItem("Wave 4"));
            this.pnlWave.Controls.Add(lbls[i]);
            this.pnlWave.Controls.Add(cblWave[i]);
            this.pnlWave.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
        }
    }

    protected void OnbtnNext2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        itemsWave = new ArrayList[countCountry];
        for (int j = 0; j < countCountry; j++)
        {
            itemsWave[j] = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (cblWave[j].Items[i].Selected) // Here i want to get the values
                {
                    itemsWave[j].Add(cblWave[j].Items[i].Value);
                }
            }
            PopulateColorCheckBoxes(itemsWave[j], j);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your `CheckBoxList cblWave` as a class variable:

```
CheckBoxList cblWave;
```

And then in your `PopulateWaveCheckBoxes` you should instantiate and fill it:

```
private void PopulateWaveCheckBoxes(ArrayList items){
Label[] lbls = new Label[items.Count];
cblWave = new CheckBoxList[items.Count];
```

Comment: Thanks Dampe, but I have already declared it as a class variable. I was reading an article to persist the values of checkboxlist at run time, is could be through ViewState. But the problem with ViewState is , it doesnt allow nonserializable objects. Since CheckBoxList is Non Serializable, I now have to mark as serializable, but for this, May be I need to make another serializable class for checkbox list. But I am not sure how to make it, or is this the only way.

Comment: Use DynamicPlaceHolder  http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx